# VBA, If value less than X then copy row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet full of data, from to the column A to column G.
How can a VBA Macro:
copy rows (not the entire row, only the column A,B,C,D,E) if the value in C<>"CLOSE" and the value in B is <19:00 And >00:00.

Edit:

I tried this solution, but when I run it, I don't find any selected cells.

```
Dim r As Range, N As Long
Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:C"))
N = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To N
    cc = Cells(i, 2).Value
    dd = Cells(i, 3).Value
    If cc >= "19:00" And cc < "00:00" And dd <> "Close" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 5)).Select
    End If

Next i
```

I've already tried to use the letters instead of the numbers to indicate the columns (...Cells(i,A) instead of Cells(i,1)) but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to put only the essential information in my question, and I think that "it is likely to be searched by someone else". If there are any other problems, please let me understand wich they are.

Comment: I've just edited my question. I didn't do it before because I don't really know whether it could be a good starting point. By the way, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No, the value must be 19<X<00 (so values like 19.30-20-21 etc...).  
And I need to copy it in to another workbook.

Comment: Your coded logic doesn't match the > and < and also is the value in the cell 0 and 19? "00" and "19"" ? or something else?

Comment: Sorry but, why the codec doesn't match ? If cc>19 And cc<00 is equal to 19<cc<00 (?)
The value in the cell is "19:00" , but I've already tried all the forms (19/19:00 or 00/00:00) and they didn't work.

Comment: @EnzoEnzk `cc>19` means *cc is more than 19*.  `cc<00` means *cc is less than 0*. Since `0` is less than `19`, what possible value for `cc` could satisfy those conditions simultaneously?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you're right, but in my case 19:00 and 00:00 are hours in day. I mean, cc>19:00 means "after 19" or at least is what I would say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, time As Variant
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 3) = "CLOSE" Then GoTo SkipLoop
        'extract just hour and see if it's less than 19
        If CInt(Left(Cells(i, 2), 2)) < 19 Then GoTo SkipLoop

        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Select
SkipLoop:
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it selects only the last row, with time of 23:30.

Comment: The format is 'text', but I've tried even with 'time' or 'number' format, and it didn't work.

Comment: @EnzoEnzk Try updated answer. It works with text formatted cells.

Comment: When I run the macro, it returns a "type mismatch" error.  
  `If CInt(Left(Cells(i, 2), 2)) < 19 Then`

Comment: Edit: I've just bypassed the problem by simply filtering the columns and then select all the result.

Comment: @EnzoEnzk Ok, so you had some other values there, which I didn't know about. But I am happy that you could make it work. If my answer solved your problem you should accept it and optionally upvote :)

Comment: Sure, I really appreciated your help, it was very usefull ! I've upvoted your answer but my reputation is too low so it's not publicly displayed. Thanks a lot again !